# Schedule IO problem via udev by-id

Tags: linux, kernel, udev, block-device, scheduling

As the title, i'm trying to set the scheduler from boot by inserting the various disks using the `udev` rules. The problem is that indicating the disk by id (`/dev/disk/by-id`) in the udev rules (in the `KERNEL==` entry), it is as if it were not taken into consideration. If I try to insert, however, the classic nomenclature (`sda`) works. How can I attach a specific scheduler to a specific disk via disk id/serial with `udev`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENV{FOO}` where `FOO` is one of the `E:` listed in `udevadm info /dev/sdX`. (For example, `ID_SERIAL`.)

You can probably use a `SYMLINK` match for one of the `S:`, i.e., the actual symlink path without `/dev/` as well.

P.S. You probably need to make sure your udev rule file is ordered after `60-persistent-storage.rules` (which sets the `E:` s and creates the symlinks), i.e., name it e.g. `61-something.rules`.